# Unable to see Always On option in Azure function Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Unable to see Always On option in Azure function Configuration.

I have an Azure function app timed trigger every 10 mins. This app is expected to run 2 hours atleast. So I kept **functionTimeOut** at 3 hours in **host.json** file.
My Function App is running on **Premium** App service plan and **EP3** Sku.

Without the Always On option, my function app is exiting 10 mins. Can someone tell me how to set the app not to exit after 10 mins?

Answer (score 0):

I found that `Always on` option is now only available in Dedicated App service plan.

`Always on` option is removed from `Premium plan`.
For reference check this [Azure Functions GitHub document](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Enable-Always-On-when-running-on-dedicated-App-Service-Plan).

**`Premium Plan`:**

***`Always on`* option not available**

[image]

**`Dedicated App Service Plan`:**

***`Always on`* available**

[image]